# Azure Data Tables timeout when querying over 1,000 records

Tags: c#, azure

I am facing an issue of timeout when using the azure.data.tables package to query the azure data(https://xxx.table.core.windows.net) with more than 1,000 records. Can this be resolved?

---

More details about the issue:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample4QueryEntities.md
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Timeout-and-Pagination

Answer (score 0):

you can increase Query timeout in up to 60 minutes.

1. Open [Azure Data Explorer](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/home)
2. Go to right hand side Gear icon click.
3. under settings -> Click on connection.
4. Increase Query timeout(in Minutes).

[image]

[image]

[Query data in the Azure Data Explorer web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-query-data)

In case of fetching data from azure database tables take more time you can use [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination).

Comment: Thanks for your support, but currently I must use https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables for my product but there is no way to use the pagination with this :(

Comment: you can read these documents, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination for timeout and pagination.